# Service account authentication issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm getting 403 errors using Google's PHP SDK when trying to list or store objects in a bucket (all operations really).

```
Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException: {
  "error": {
    "errors": [ {
      "domain": "global",
      "reason": "forbidden",
      "message": "my-service-account@example-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to storage."
    } ],
    "code": 403,
    "message": "my-service-account@example-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.list access to storage."
  }
}
```

I have set up a service account, gave it the StorageObjectAdmin role which includes the following permissions:

```
resourcemanager.projects.get
resourcemanager.projects.list
storage.objects.create
storage.objects.delete
storage.objects.get
storage.objects.getIamPolicy
storage.objects.list
storage.objects.setIamPolicy
storage.objects.update
```

I have downloaded the JSON key file for the service account and use when creating the PHP client. Still, when I make a request on any operation I get the mentioned 403 Forbidden error.

Where should I look to resolve this?

Comment: Turns out the wrong bucket names was calculated programmatically, worked well after fixing that.

Comment: `my-service-account@example-project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com` catches my eye; does the identifier in your PHP match the service account key being used? (If not, it would appear as though that's your problem.)

Comment: Can you post your solution (which you posted as a comment) as an actual solution to your own question, and mark it accepted?